# SPSS Calculate variable based on values of other variables BUT not necessarily all variables need to meet conditions

Tags: spss

I'd like to create a new variable based on values of other variables (which is absolutely simple) BUT I encounter the problem when I need to find what function I should use when it gets to make specific condition.
The problem is I need an output 0-1 (1 when the condition is met & 0 when it's not) but not all the variables need to met this condition but at least 6 from all of 9.
In following example the condition is that the output will be 1 when all variables met condition and I need to specify that at least 6 from them need to do so:

```
Q25=3 & Q39=2 & Q38=1 & Q37=3 & Q36=2 & 
Q35=1 & Q34=1 & Q33=3 & Q32=2
```

I tried to find solutions in group of functions but didn't find the specific one. Hope I wrote it clear enough to understand my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a logical condition, you can turn this into a mathematical condition. SPSS treats each logical value as a mathematical 0-1 value too, so:

```
compute YourNewVar=sum(Q25=3, Q39=2, Q38=1, Q37=3, Q36=2, 
Q35=1, Q34=1, Q33=3, Q32=2)>=6.
```